# netmiko connection.send_command(("openstack network show grep {} --fit | grep 'some1\|some2'".format(var1 var2), expect_string=r"#")

Tags: python, netmiko

I am trying netmiko send.command with two variable

how do i do that

this is a example of one variable =>

```
connection.send_command('openstack network show {0} --fit | grep physical_network'.format(netnm),  expect_string=r"#")
```

i need this to make work ==>

```
connection.send_command("openstack network show grep {} --fit | grep 'provider:segmentation_id\|provider:physical_network'".format((netnm,netno)),  expect_string=r"#")
```

Comment: Put `{0}` in the string where the first variable should be, and put `{1}` where the second variable should be.